# Jquery Mobile List Click

Tags: jquery, listview, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've created a mobile listview below with Jquery and it's rendering just fine. What I want some help with is when you click on a particular list element - right now I have it set that it goes onto a new page and it shows the resteraunt id. What I want to try and do is that the same information of the specific listview entry that was clicked would be rendered on the new page, meaning all the info I had before in the list element clicked would be rendered on the new page in just a simple paragraph. It's me trying to get my head around this dynamic listviews is where im having trouble. Can anyone please help? I'd really appreciate it - the database information is reading over perfectly!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Find A Deal</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>
        img.fullscreen {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        </style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
        $("#list").empty();
        var url="http://localhost/test/json3.php";
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            //loop through deals
            $.each(json.deals,function(i,dat){
                $("#list").append("<li><a id='"+dat.restaurantid+"'><h1>"+dat.name+"</h1><p>"+dat.dname+"</p></a></li>");
                $(document).on('click', '#'+dat.restaurantid, function(event){  
                    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                    {
                        listObject.itemID = $(this).attr('id'); 
                        $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                });            
            });
            $("#list").listview('refresh');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function(){       
        $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').html('You have selected Link' + listObject.itemID);
    });

    var listObject = {
        itemID : null
    }    
</script>
</head>     
<body>    
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Current Deals</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/findadeal/index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/findadeal/mydeal.html" data-icon="grid">My Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--New Page --> 

<div data-role="page" id="index2">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1> Find A Deal </h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" href="#page1" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left">Get Deal </a>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#index" data-icon="grid">My Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below example which is based on the code you've posted, the selected id is passed from page index to page index2.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Find A Deal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <style>
            img.fullscreen {
                max-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function () {
                $("#list").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    $("#list").append (
                        $(["<li><a id='id_",i ,"'><h1>H1_label_",i,"</h1><p>P_label_",i,"</p></a></li>"].join("")).
                        on('click', ['#id_',i].join (""), function(e){  
                            if(e.handled !== true) {
                                listObject.itemID = this.id;                                
                                $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
                                e.handled = true;
                            }
                        })
                    );
                }
                $("#list").listview('refresh');
            });

            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function () {

                //selected id on page transition
                alert(['selected id: ',listObject.itemID].join(""));
            });

            var listObject = {
                itemID: null
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                 <h1>Current Deals</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://localhost/findadeal/index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://localhost/findadeal/mydeal.html" data-icon="grid">My Deals</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--New Page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="index2">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1> Find A Deal </h1> 
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <a data-role="button" href="#page1" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left">Get Deal</a>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <nav data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#index" data-icon="grid">My Deals</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a feeling I was explaining myself wrong, what I'm hoping to achieve is that when a user clicks one of the elements on the original list it will load up a new page. On this new page the "dat.restaurantid, dat.name and dat.dname" only to do with that list item selected would be pulled from the database and shown on the new page in the form of a paragraph (<p></p>) I hope that explains things better? My apologise!

Comment: I've updated my post. The selected list item id is passed from page index to index 2. In the same way you can pass any information you want from page index to page index2. When the pagebeforeshow event is triggered for page index2, you know the selected id so you can show specific data based on the selected id.

Answer (score 0):

Render data in Listview and on each click/touchstart of list, show data on another page.

// first function

```
function render(){        
    var html="";
    html +=   "<li id="+index+"><a href='#'><img src='images/new-iaav-72.png' class='ui-   corner-none' style='width:50px;height:56px'>";

    html +=   "<div style='margin-left:-10%;margin-top:-2%'><h1>"+title +"</h1>  </div>";         
    html +=   "</a></li>";                         
    $("#xyz div:jqmData(role=content) #ul1").append (html);

   func1 = function() {showDetails(index,title,descrp,image_large);};
   document.getElementById(index).addEventListener("click", func1);
```

}

// Second function to render data on second page.

```
 function showDetails(){

   if(image_large!="")
    $('#setDetailImage').attr("src",image_large);
else        
    $('#setDetailImage').attr("src",'images/defaultDog.png');

$('#setDetailTitle').text(title);   
$('#setDetailDescription').html(descrp).text();

 }
```